# Kubuntu 22.04.2 can’t use 4090 eGPU after the update yesterday

Tags: nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, 22.04

So I am running Kubuntu 22.04.2 on my 13700HX laptop and have been using a 4090 eGPU. After yesterday’s update of the system, it stops working. The GUI can’t start up, so I entered command line mode and login. What’s funny is that, when I `poweroff`, the Kubuntu poweroff graphics works perfectly and showed on my display. Any solution for this? Thanks.

Update:
error message at boot:

`GET_CURRENT_CAM command failed`

Update2:
It looks like `nvidia-driver-535-open` is broken, so `nvidia-driver-535` is installed instead. This might be the reason to break things.